How to read Kyowa strain cage specification?
These pics are from Kyowa strain cage specification which came with the strain cages.

In "thermal output" formula there are T1, T2, T3 and T4. What are those? I would understand if there was just one T for the temperature you are interested in finding out the thermal output.

Does this "thermal output" include "temperature coefficient of cage factor"? Or it needs to added to "thermal output" to get the total effect of tempereature on strain cage output?

Why does it say "Based on Instrument G.F. of 2.00" when the spec states that G.F. of these strain cages is 2.13 +/-1.0%?





I thought I was going to learn about something new called a strain cage :)  I think you mean strain gage/gauge.


It's a biquadratic (4th degree)  polynomial in T (°C) fitted to the real-world characteristics. You measure T, and stick it in the equation to get the thermal output.

I interpret this as the 'zero shift' whereas the gauge factor is the 'span shift'. So you add the two effects.

I believe it's a generic graph- some KFGS gauges have GF of 1.9 or 2.0 or 2.1


I suggest studying the catalogs and introductory document you can get from Kyowa's website.

I'll be referencing Vishay's TN504, which gives an excellent overview of this, in more detail than I can fit into this short answer. I highly recommend consulting it for the full details, including greater background context on how these calculations were motivated. I recommend consulting the docs linked from Kyowa's website as well, which Spehro Pefhany links in his answer.

In "thermal output" formula there are T1, T2, T3 and T4. What are those? I would understand if there was just one T for the temperature you are interested in finding out the thermal output.

T^1, T^2, T^3, T^4 are the first, second, third, and fourth powers of the temperature in celsius (at the top, this is annotated as "T: Temperature/温度 [°C]"). Note that these are superscripts (commonly used to denote exponentiation), not subscripts.
This comes from a fourth-degree polynomial fit.

Does this "thermal output" include "temperature coefficient of cage factor"? Or it needs to added to "thermal output" to get the total effect of tempereature on strain cage output?

These are separate, and have different units/axes on the chart anyway. The dotted line reflects the response from just heating and cooling of the gauge, while the solid line reflects the additional change to the gauge coefficient as a result of that temperature.
TN504 gives a sample calculation:

Start with an uncorrected strain measurement \$\hat{\hat{\epsilon}}\$
Subtract just the thermal output to get a strain measurement free of the thermal output, but still subject to the tempco of the gauge factor: \$\hat{\epsilon} = \hat{\hat{\epsilon}} - \epsilon_{TO}\$ (see next section for caveats)
Now, \$\hat{\epsilon}\$ may be converted to a strain by using the correct G.F. (from the device/lot specs + the effect of temperature on the GF)


Why does it say "Based on Instrument G.F. of 2.00" when the spec states that G.F. of these strain cages is 2.13 +/-1.0%?

TN504 gets into this a bit as well. In short, the instrument used for the readout may be set to a G.F. of 2.00 (by convention). The physical gauge has some value, not quite 2.00, roughly set by design and then characterized when the lot is tested+qualified.
Meanwhile, the T/O is given in terms of a strain (microns per meter), but the physical output of the strain gauge is electrical.
The gauge is read out electrically, with a physical T/O (output contribution due to temperature); the actual T/O (in terms of strain) would be corrected using an equation similar to (again, quoting from that reference note):
\$ \epsilon_{TO}\prime = \epsilon_{TO} \frac{2.0}{\text{actual G.F.}}\$
